# Command not found when running Bash script, but works when running command directly

Tags: linux, bash, apache, lets-encrypt

I've been using letsencrypt to generate SSL certificates for my site, more specifically letsencrypt_webfaction. When I run this command in my project, it works

```
letsencrypt_webfaction --letsencrypt_account_email <Email I use> --domains <domains I use> --public <public_file> --username <username> --password <password>
```

However, when I run the same command in a bash script, I get the error

```
generate_certificate.sh: line 2: letsencrypt_webfaction: command not found
```

I made sure I had all possible permissions on the bash script using chmod 777 generate_certificate.sh, but still nothing. On top of that I have a bash script that runs right before that, which simply restarts Apache, and that works fine.

I read other S.O articles, such as this one, and tried running ***dos2unix script.sh***, which did run successfully, but when I tried running the bash script again, it didn't work.

Restart Apache Script

```
#!/bin/bash
../apache2/bin/./restart
#END
```

Generate SSL Script

```
#!/bin/bash
letsencrypt_webfaction --letsencrypt_account_email <Email I use> --domains <domains I use> --public <public_file> --username <username> --password <password>
#END
```

I'm a python developer, and don't have much experience with Ruby, so excuse my ignorance, but the letsencrypt_webfaction command is a function in my bash profile.

~/.bash_profile

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

function letsencrypt_webfaction {
    PATH=$PATH:$GEM_HOME/bin GEM_HOME=$HOME/.letsencrypt_webfaction/gems RUBYLIB=$GEM_HOME/lib ruby2.2 $HOME/.letsencrypt_webfaction/gems/bin/letsencrypt_webfaction $*
}

eval "$(rbenv init -)"


PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
export TMPDIR="/home/doc4design/src/tmp"
```

Comment: Assuming `letsencrypt_webfaction` is an application, have you tried linking the path explicitly like you're doing with the apache command?

Comment: It's a function in my bash profile.

Comment: In you're generate.sh try using `$HOME/.letsencrypt_webfaction/gems/bin/letsencrypt_webfaction`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, shell functions are only available in the shell they were defined in; they're not inherited by subprocesses. Your .bash_profile is only run by the login shell, not shells that run as subprocesses (e.g. to run scripts).

- Option 1: In bash, you can run `export -f letsencrypt_webfaction` in the defining shell (i.e. in your .bash_profile), and it'll be inherited by subprocesses (provided they're also running bash).
- Option 2: You can define the function in your .bashrc instead of .bash_profile, and since you run .bashrc *from* .bash_profile it'll get defined in all your bash shells.
- Option 3: Just use the full command in the script. This would be my preference, since it makes the script more independent. Having a script depend on a shell function that's defined in a completely different place is fragile (as you're experiencing) and just a bit weird.

While I'm at it, here are some general scripting recommendations:

- In most contexts, you should put double-quotes around variable references (and strings that contain variable references) to avoid weird effects from word splitting and wildcard expansion. The right side of an assignment is one place it's ok to leave them off (e.g. `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin` and `PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"` are both ok), but I tend to recommend using quotes everywhere as it's hard to keep track of where it's safe to leave them off and where it's dangerous. For the same reason, you should almost always use `"$@"` instead of `$*` (as in the `letsencrypt_webfaction` function).

  [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net) is really good at spotting errors like this, so I recommend running your shell scripts through it and acting on its suggestions.
- Using the `function` keyword to define a function is nonstandard; the standard syntax is to use `()` after the function name, like this:

  ```
  letsencrypt_webfaction() {
      PATH="$PATH:$GEM_HOME/bin" GEM_HOME="$HOME/.letsencrypt_webfaction/gems" RUBYLIB="$GEM_HOME/lib" ruby2.2 "$HOME/.letsencrypt_webfaction/gems/bin/letsencrypt_webfaction" "$@"
  }
  ```
- The function I just gave still may not work right, since it (re)defines `GEM_HOME` *after* using it. The entire line gets parsed (and pre-existing variable definitions expanded), *then* the variables defined as prefixes to the command get included in the environment of the command. This means that the ruby script gets the updated value of `GEM_HOME`, but the updated values of `PATH` and `RUBYLIB` are based on whatever value `GEM_HOME` had when the function was run. I'm pretty sure this is not what you intended.
- In the restart apache script, you use a relative path to the `restart` command. This will be evaluated relative to the working directory of the process that runs the script, not relative to the script's location. This could be anywhere.